# SKProductsRequest fails in Xcode 12 GM in UI Tests and SKTestSession

Tags: xcode, storekit, ios14, xcode12

When I run `SKProductsRequest` from UI Tests session in Xcode 12 GM, it always fails with this error:

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "UNKNOWN_ERROR" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=UNKNOWN_ERROR, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003d30f30 {Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=507 "Error decoding object" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error decoding object, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Attempted to decode store response}}}
```

I tried to use `SKTestSession` with valid `.storekit` configuration file, but it didn't help. Though in my Unit Tests this works fine with `SKTestSession`.

Is there a way to test store in UI tests in Xcode 12 GM? Or `SKTestSession` is usable only in Unit Tests?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after few days of digging seems like I found out what to do to make it work. You just need to add some delay before running `SKProductsRequest` at app launch. I set 5 seconds delay just for UI tests — and that's it! Now my request works!

That's the line needed for the request to run without errors:

```
// Wait for StoreKitTest
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
// Start request
request.start()
```

Comment: This won't fix the issue anymore!

Comment: Still works for me.

Comment: with new version of xcode and ios won't work any more